# Finding limits of functions

Tags: code-golf, math, function

A **limit** in math determines the value that a function `f(x)` **approaches** as `x` gets closer and closer to a certain value.

Let me use the equation `f(x)=x^2/x` as an example.
Obviously, `f(x)` is undefined if x is 0 (x=0, x<sup>2</sup>=0, 0/0 is undefined).
But, what happens when we calculate `f(x)` as `x` approaches 0?

`x=0.1, f(x)=0.01/0.1 = 0.1`
`x=0.01, f(x)=0.0001/0.01 = 0.01`
`x=0.00001, f(x)=0.0000000001/0.00001 = 0.00001`
We can easily see that `f(x)` is approaching 0 as `x` approaches 0.

What about when `f(x)=1/x^2`, and we approach 0?

`x=0.1, f(x)=1/0.01=100`
`x=0.01, f(x)=1/0.0001=10000`
`x=0.00001, f(x)=1/0.0000000001=10000000000`
As `x` approaches 0, `f(x)` approaches positive infinity.

You will be given two things in whatever input format you like:

- `f(x)` as an `eval`-able string in your language
- `a` as a floating point

Output the value that `f(x)` approaches when `x` approaches `a`. Do not use any built-in functions that explicitly do this.

**Input Limitations:**

- The limit of `f(x)` as `x` approaches `a` will always exist.
- There will be real-number values just before and just after `f(a)`: you will never get `f(x)=sqrt(x), a=-1` or anything of the sort as input.

**Output Specifications:**

- If `f(x)` approaches positive or negative infinity, output `+INF` or `-INF`, respectively.
- If `f(a)` is a real number, then output `f(a)`.

**Test Cases:**

```
f(x)=sin(x)/x, a=0; Output: 1
f(x)=1/x^2, a=0; Output: +INF
f(x)=(x^2-x)/(x-1), a=1; Output: 1
f(x)=2^x, a=3; Output: 8
```

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: What would you like to have displayed in the case of `f(x)=1/x` and `a=0`

Comment: @Matt: You will never get that input. `The limit of f(x) as x approaches a will always exist.`

Comment: A mathematician wouldn't say "the limit exists" in a case like 1/x² | ₓ→₀, but I suppose it's clear what you mean.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What would they call it then? Indeterminate? :) I'd like to know.

Comment: At least in standard analysis they'd just say "the function diverges for _x_ → 0". The destinction between positive and negative infinity is quite cumbersome (and hardly worth it) when doing proper mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python <s>146</s> 185

Figured I'd post the obvious answer before anyone else does.
Note, reads two lines from `stdin` with `f(x)` on the first 
and `a` on the second.

**Edit:** Made it actually work, as per `beary`'s comment
**Edit 2:** `i` is much smaller, so there are much fewer inputs that it should fail for.

```
from math import*
f,a,i=eval("lambda x:"+input()),eval(input()),2e-308
while 1:
 try:
     r=str(f(a+i)).upper()
     if'NAN'!=r:break
 except:
     i*=-2
print('I'==r[0]and'+'+r or r)
```

Comment: Can you put in the input format? Also, you seem to have neglected the sign on the INF (it should be +inf or -inf). I really don't mind "obvious" answers, as long as it works without any functions calculating it.

Comment: This is probably being overly picky, but this does not work for `f(x) = 1/x, a = -1*10^-161` and `f(x) = 1/(x-1*10^-161), a = 0`

Comment: Darn, I guess I'll have to make `i` the smallest float possible, which should bandadge those problems.

Comment: python provides a machine epsilon as `sys.float_info.epsilon`, which is probably more accurate for what you're attempting

Comment: Thanks for that `ardnew`, though I think you meant `sys.float_info.min`? `i` in my code is nearly that on my machine (saving a few characters, sacrificing portability).

Comment: @walpen: No, the `min` value will provide the smallest possible representable number in the FPS, but your calculated values `a+min` may not necessarily be representable. Using epsilon will guarantee a value `a+e` that is not equal to `a`

Comment: Unfortunately, `epsilon` will give the wrong answer for the cases Matt gave (at least with the very basic algorithm I used), which is why starting at about `min` and working up to larger values seems to work in more cases. (Though the opposite, starting at epsilon and working down to the smallest representable in that case, is probably a more optimal algorithm).

Comment: @walpen i see. your code seems to be shorter then! (i cant get it to run any tests (saved source in `file.py`, run `python file.py`?))

Comment: Ex input: `echo "1/x" > input; echo 0 >> input; cat input | python3 file.py`

Answer (score 4):

### C, 402 bytes

Plenty of room for golfing, just proof of concept to begin with :P

Compiles under clang, osx.

Note: For linux you may have to change the code to use something like: "ld -shared f.o -o f.so -lm"

```
#include<dlfcn.h>
#include<stdio.h>
float e,r;
main(int i,char**v){
    // create and compile temporary c file for 'f(x)'
    // note: include offset within function
    FILE*s=fopen("f.c","w");
    fprintf(s,"#include<math.h>\nfloat f(float x){x+=%s;return %s;}",v[2],v[1]); 
    fclose(s);
    system("cc -fPIC -c f.c;ld -bundle f.o -o f.so -lm");
    float(*f)(float)=dlsym(dlopen("f.so",0),"f");

    for(i=0;1;e=(e==0)?1e-37:e*2){
        r=f(e);
        if(isinf(r))i=1;else if(!isnan(r)){
            i?printf("%cINF\n",r>0?43:45):printf("%f\n",r);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Run as:

```
./a.out "sin(x)/x" 0
./a.out "1/(x*x)" 0
./a.out "(x*x-x)/(x-1)" 1
./a.out "pow(2,x)" 3
```

Results:

```
1.000000
+INF
1.000000
8.000000
```